# Para que serve o modo de exibição de compatibilidade do Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

Estou com problemas no *layout* com usuários que usam o browser Internet Explorer em modo de exibição de compatibilidade.

Ao usar o Internet Explorer versão 11.0.21 em modo de exibição de compatibilidade qual será a versão que ele irá assumir? A anterior ou alguma especifica?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito vaga não podemos te ajudar assim. Especifique-a.

Comment: Minha pergunta é exatamente como está acima, para que serve a exibição de compatibilidade no internet explorer como ela se comporta, ela assume alguma versão anterior? ou apenas começa interpretar comandos que estão obsoletos. Obrigado!

Comment: você não fez essa pergunta "Para que serve a exibição em modo de compatibilidade no ie (...)" porque essa pergunta a resposta está com a própria Microsoft que desenvolveu isso http://windows.microsoft.com/pt-br/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/compatibility-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O Internet Explorer dispõe de vários modos de renderização para as diferentes versões do navegador. Temos desde o 5 (chamado de IE Quirks) até o Edge que é o modo de renderização associado ao IE11 e implementa vários recursos novos de CSS3.

Cada versão possui recursos novos e também torna obsoletos comportamentos/recursos que antes funcionavam. Nesse [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn467846(v=vs.85).aspx), a Microsoft explica as mudanças de compatibilidade do IE por versão.

Quando o IE recebe um HTML, ele fará a renderização da página usando o modo de renderização que ele considerar mais compatível. Mas é possível também especificar no HTML, através da tag Meta, qual versão de renderização do IE é a mais adequada para sua página.

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

> Vale lembrar que o Microsoft Edge ignora essa tag Meta.

Agora, voltando para a questão, para saber exatamente a versão que o IE está usando para exibir seu site, acesse a **ferramenta do desenvolvedor (F12)**. Na aba de emulador, ele indicará o modo de renderização padrão do seu site e, quando estiver no modo de compatibilidade, a versão do modo de renderização que ele está usando.

Para mais informações, tem o artigo ["Como fazer o IE exibir melhor o meu site?"](http://talkitbr.com/2015/08/24/como-fazer-o-ie-exibir-melhor-o-meu-site/).